# Using bootstrap, jquery and javascript to create a dynamic homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've been messing around with bootstrap, jquery, javascript and html for some time now and I still find it rather difficult considering the way that pages, navigation and etc works. One thing in particular that I've had some trouble finding answers for is the best way/practice to build a page..?

I've tried the following for my page, but I always find something that doesn't quite work as I expect it to.

- Creating an "empty" (containing empty divs) index page and using javascript to load external pages (Problem: I can't seem to use the id's or classes of the elements in the external page anymore with this approach)
- Creating a single index.html page containing all my divs and hiding/showing whatever I need to (Problem: Quickly becomes very hard to find around in which are showing/hiding and adding stuff can become quite tricky
- Creating a single html file for all the "pages" I need (Problem: I can't seem to transfer my javascript vars from one page to another. The vars become empty on loading a new page using href)

## Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Course Suggestion Tool</title>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/functions.js"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link href="css/custom_style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-c">

<div class="container" id="first">
  <div id="study_area">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Study</legend>
    <div class="dropdown" id="study_dropdown">
      <button id="study" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Study
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="dme" data-value="action-1" id="dme">Digital Media Engineering</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4 id="study_choice">Study choice</h4>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  </div>

  <div id="focus_area">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Focus Area</legend>
      <div class="dropdown" id="focus_dropdown">
        <button id="study" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Focus
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#" id="smaa">Social media and apps</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="uxue">UX User experience</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="ds">Data science</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="cga">Computer games</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="cgr">Computer graphics</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h4 id="focus_choice">Focus Choice</h4>
    </fieldset>
  </div>

  <button id="next_page" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Something exciting</button>
</div>

<div class="container" id="second">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

## NB

The content consists of two dropdowns. On the page load I only want to show the first one. Then once the user selects something from that dropdown I want to show which he selected in a heading and show the second dropdown as well. Once the second one has been selected too I want to display the selection in a heading and show a button that "navigates the user to a new page". However what's really import is that I want to "save" the name of the dropdowns that the user selected to use as some sort of feedback.´

## Functions.js

```
var selection = {};

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#focus_area").addClass("collapse");
  $("#study_choice").hide();
  $("#focus_choice").hide();
  $("#next_page").hide();

  $(".dme").click(function() {
    $("#study_dropdown").hide()
    var choiceText = $("#dme").text()
    selection.study = choiceText;
    $("#study_choice").text(choiceText)
    $("#study_choice").show()
    $("#focus_area").slideDown();
  });

  $("#smaa").click(function() {
    $("#focus_dropdown").hide();
    var choiceText = $("#smaa").text();
    selection.focus = choiceText;
    $("#focus_choice").text(choiceText);
    $("#focus_choice").show();
    $("#next_page").slideDown();
  });

  $("#uxue").click(function(){
    $("#focus_dropdown").hide();
    var choiceText = $("#uxue").text();
    selection.focus = choiceText;
    $("#focus_choice").text(choiceText);
    $("#focus_choice").show();
    $("#next_page").slideDown();
  });

  $("#ds").click(function(){
    $("#focus_dropdown").hide();
    var choiceText = $("#ds").text();
    selection.focus = choiceText;
    $("#focus_choice").text(choiceText);
    $("#focus_choice").show();
    $("#next_page").slideDown();
  });

  $("#cga").click(function(){
    $("#focus_dropdown").hide();
    var choiceText = $("#cga").text();
    selection.focus = choiceText;
    $("#focus_choice").text(choiceText);
    $("#focus_choice").show();
    $("#next_page").slideDown();
  });

  $("#cgr").click(function(){
    $("#focus_dropdown").hide();
    var choiceText = $("#cgr").text();
    selection.focus = choiceText;
    console.log(selection);
    $("#focus_choice").text(choiceText);
    $("#focus_choice").show();
    $("#next_page").slideDown();
  });

  $("#next_page").click(function() {
    $("#first").load();
    $("#second").load("planner.html") //External html page (currently empty)
  });
```

});

Comment: have you written any javascript code?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements that will explain how to fix the issue of not being able to access things when loaded dynamically.

Comment: Need to scale this down to more specific issues and provide code that isn't working for the specific problem

Comment: But more importantly, you really need to research general web design and functionality before you start coding. No offense meant but your questions demonstrate a lack of fundamental understanding of how web pages and JavaScript work

Comment: @SRK Yes. I have written javascript code to hide and show the elements.

Comment: please share to go ahead

Comment: @SRK Done.. Updated the entire html code too to illustrate what I'm trying to do..

Comment: [I would start here to learn more about this topic](https://www.codeschool.com/learn/javascript).  They have very good introductions on not just how, but also the why.

Comment: I can also add [here](http://tutorialzine.com/2015/02/single-page-app-without-a-framework/) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn463786.aspx) and [here](http://www.awwwards.com/practical-uses-of-angularjs-create-a-single-page-application-spa-or-a-website-menu-in-an-instant.html) and [here](http://singlepageappbook.com/single-page.html) - depending on what your flavor is.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Currently it looks like I'm leaning towards using AngularJS. 

I am still uncertain as to what the best practice for developing a web page is, as I didn't get any response. Currently I have one page that I just plan on showing and hiding stuff in it seems. I doubt however that this will be very "pretty" in the long run..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you want to create is a [Single Page Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn463786.aspx).

Your high level requirements will be:

1. Loading and destroying parts of pages (aka modules) dynamically.
2. State transitions to cover various use cases.
3. Dynamically bind and update the state based on user input like `click`.

While you can surely code your own solution using jQuery, Bootstrap etc I would highly recommend using a MV* framework for creating such a single page application. There are many popular ones like Angular, Ember, Backbone etc that make the process much more easier. React can also be a good view component.

These frameworks provide many features that will make the task of creating dynamic web applications easier.

I know this is not the exact answer you were looking for, but I hope this answer could guide you towards the right approach that will be easier to implement and maintain in the long term.

Comment: Thanks. When I wrote the above question I didn't have much experience in Web programming. However I do now. And yes. The above suggestion is probably the best way to make a proper web page. I haven't tried all the solutions, but I can certainly say that ASP.Net (MVC) is a good approach. And same with Angular, however I find ASP.Net to be the most "noob" friendly. And with the "new" .Net Core Framework, Microsoft has come out with a pretty good "tutorial" for creating more custom features/functionality.